# how to sort text file in C using struct?

Tags: c, sorting, struct, linked-list, text-files

I am trying to sort a text file based on member's age. My code doesn't work only because third and fourth lines have last column (town) missing. If all lines have same information ( suppose, 3rd and 4th lines have the name of the town/city), it works fine. In my way, when struct reads 3rd line, it reads first word from 4th line as town/city.

Here is my codes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct _Member{
    char *name;
    int age;
    int id;
    char *town;
}Member;

int main() {

    FILE *file = fopen("member.txt", "r");
    FILE *newFile = fopen("new_member.txt", "w");

    int counter=0, line = 10;
    int i;
    Member *member = malloc(sizeof(Member)*line);

    for(i =0; i<line; i++){
        int len = 12;
        char *name = malloc(sizeof(char)*(len+1));
        name [len] = '\0';
        int age;
        int id;
        char *town = malloc(sizeof(char)*(len+1));
        town [len] = '\0';

        fscanf(file,"%s %i %i %s\n", name, &age, &id, town);

        member[counter].name = name;
        member[counter].age = age;
        member[counter].id = id;
        member[counter].town = town;

        counter++;
    }
    while(1){
    int swapped = 0, i, j;
    Member temp;
    for (i = 1; i < counter; i++){
        for(j = 0; j <counter - i; j++){
        if(member[j].age > member[j+1].age){
            temp = member[j];
            member[j]=member[j+1];
            member[j+1] = temp;
            swapped = 1;
        }
        }
    }
    if(swapped ==0){
        break;
    }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < counter; i++){
        fprintf(newFile,"%s %d %d %s\n", member[i].name, member[i].age, member[i].id, member[i].town);
    }

    fclose(file);
    fclose(newFile);

    printf("Successful\n");

    return 0;
}
```

member.txt file:

```
John 23 3456 Edinburgh
Robert 33 4567 London
Peter 45 4345 
Cary 56 12345 
Diane 45 4587 Norfolk
Will 32 3453 Essex
Paul 56 7896 York
Alisha 78 1234 Peterbourgh
Brandon 45 3214 Brighton
Eli 39 5234 Oxford
```

result after sorting; new_member.txt file

```
John 23 3456 Edinburgh
Will 32 3453 Essex
Robert 33 4567 London
Eli 39 5234 Oxford
Peter 45 4345 Cary
Diane 45 4587 Norfolk
Brandon 45 3214 Brighton
Paul 56 7896 York
Alisha 78 1234 Peterbourgh
56 12345 4345
```

How can I solve this problem? or what may be the other approach to sort this type of files? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Read first three, then check for existance of fourth and assign if possible. Make sure that there is no \n while reading the four arguments. If one is encountered, assume the current row had less than four (or three) and start the new row.

Comment: Your `fscanf` will capture the name of next entry if there's no city there. You could `getline` to get the entire line and than use `sscanf`, but you still have to check if you have all the required fields. A nice way of doing this would be writing `splitString` method.

Comment: Unrelated, but you should check if `fopen` returns `NULL`. Just to prevent the next SO question.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. and trying all suggestions (y)